# search for a value in the array using mongo shell

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a collection with below docs of below format. I wanted to search through the array and insert value into variable.

```
_id: "Normal", charge: true,
  Name: "Normal", Desc: "Normal",
  timestamp: ISODate("2016-05-16"),
  asset:[{idi: "AssetOne", measure: {unitMax:64, unitMin: 36, uCount: 366}},
  {idi: "AssetTwo", measure: {unitMax:64, unitMin: 36, uCount: 366}}]
```

In the above scenario **asset** is an array of embedded docs.
Now I have another variable **id** which will store **assetid** 
If **id** is **AssetOne**, I want to store **unitMax, unitMin & uCount values in umax, umin, uc variables respectively**.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: **id** is a local variable where it gets calculated by some function. So now assume **id** has got value **AssetOne**. Here I should search in the document given above and should push **unitMax, unitMin & uCount values into variables**. Please let me know if you require more info on this.

Comment: **id** is a local variable where it gets calculated by some function. So now assume **id** has got value **AssetOne**. Here I should search in the document given above and if **asset.idi matches with id** we should push **unitMax, unitMin & uCount values into another local variables.** Please let me know if you require more info on this